# How to store the value of an input inside a popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to store the value of an input inside a .popover but, when I close and reopen the .popover the value is different. It looks like the decimal places are not obeying the stored value.

My Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#popovername1').popover({
    html: true,
    sanitize: false,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'right',
    title: 'Estimar preço máximo',
    content: function() {
      // Intro
      var intropopoverinc1 = $('<div id="colosso1">').html('<strong style="font-size: 30px; display:block; color: #333333; width: 500px;"> Escreva aqui todo o seu texto, por favor. Não esqueça de colocar a marca.</strong>');

      // Input
      var inputElement = $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'text',
        id: 'inputcenariosinc1',
        placeholder: 'Digite um valor'
      });

      // Popover content
      var popoverContent = $('<div>').attr('id', 'flex1');
      popoverContent.append(intropopoverinc1);
      popoverContent.append(inputElement); // Adiciona o input abaixo da introdução

      return popoverContent;
    },
    trigger: 'click'
  });
});

var inputcenariosinc1 = ''; // Variável global para armazenar o valor do input

$(function() {
  $(document).on('inserted.bs.popover', '#popovername1', function() {
    $('#inputcenariosinc1').val(inputcenariosinc1); // Define o valor do input

    $('#inputcenariosinc1').on('input', function() {
      inputcenariosinc1 = $(this).val(); // Atualiza a variável global com o valor do input
    });

    $(document).on('input', '#inputcenariosinc1', function() {
      var input = this;
      var prefix = 'R$';
      var value = input.value;

      // Remove caracteres não numéricos
      value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');

      if (value !== '') {
        // Divide por 100 para ajustar os decimais
        var number = parseFloat(value) / 100;

        // Formata o valor com separador de milhar e decimais
        value = number.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2,
          maximumFractionDigits: 2
        });
        value = prefix + '' + value.replace('.', '.');
      }

      input.value = value;
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.6.3/nouislider.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.6.3/nouislider.min.css'>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button id='popovername1' style='background-color: red; color: white;'>
      Pop1
</button>
```

See that the decimal places seem to change, this cannot happen. The same value I type when the .popover is open should be the same when I close and reopen it countless times.

Comment: Don't add an event handler inside another event handler. Every time the first event happens, you add another handler for the second event.